# If $p(X),q(X)\in R[X]$ are primitive and $R$ is an integral domain, then $ap(X)=bq(X)$ imply $a$ and $b$ are associates.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

Proposition: Let $a,b \in R$. If $p(X),q(X)\in R[X]$ are primitive and $R$ is an integral domain, then $ap(X)=bq(X)$ imply $a$ and $b$ are associates; so are $p(X)$ and $q(X)$.

Proof:

Let 
\begin{align}
p(X) &= p_mX^m + p_{m-1}X^{m-1} + \cdots + p_1X + p_0\\
q(X) &= q_nX^n + q_{n-1}X^{n-1} + \cdots + q_1X + q_o
\end{align}
By definition of a primitive,
\begin{align}
\forall r, \overline{r} \in R ((r \mid p_0, p_1, \cdots, p_m \quad \land \quad \overline{r} \mid q_0, q_1,\cdots, q_n)\Leftrightarrow (\text{$r$ and $\overline{r}$ are units of $R$.})).
\end{align}
Suppose $ap(X)=bq(X)$, then $m=n$ and $\forall i=0,1, \cdots, n(ap_i=bq_i)$. It follows, $a \mid bq_0, bq_1, \cdots, bq_n$ and $b\mid ap_0,ap_1, \cdots, ap_n$. Note that $a$ and $b$ are either prime or not prime. If either one of them are prime, then, by Lemma 3, $b \nmid p_0, p_1, \cdots, p_n$. It follows, $a=bu$ and since primes are irreducible, $u \in R$ is a unit. Hence, $a$ and $b$ are associates. Also, by substitution of $a$ with $bu$ and cancellation of $b$, $p(X)$ and $q(X)$ are associates.

> I don't know how to proceed when neither $a$ nor $b$ are prime. :(

Comment: This is not true in arbitrary integral domains.  In the notes at http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~radford/math516f06/RRXUFD.pdf which you're presumably referencing (inferring from previous question), $R$ is assumed to be a unique factorization domain.  Since you understand the case when one of $a,b$ is prime, I think you will have no trouble figuring this out over a UFD, where we have prime factorization.  Actually, the proposition remains true when $R$ is just assumed to be a GCD domain (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GCD_domain), and Gauss' Lemma also generalizes well.

Comment: Hint: over a GCD domain: $\large \,a\mid bq_0,\ldots,bq_n\,\Rightarrow\,a\mid (bq_0,\ldots,bq_n)\approx b(q_0,\ldots,q_n)\approx b.\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque: What does $\approx$ stand for? Thanks guys, I solved it now, knowing $R$ is a UFD.

Comment: It means *associate*, i.e $\, a\approx b\iff  a\mid b\mid a.\,$ In a domain this is equivalent to $\,a = u b$ for a unit $u.\ $   Generally gcds are defined only up associateness (up to unit factors in domains).